# Add php code to widget title in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget

I would like to add php code to widget title :

```
カジノゲーム  <?php 
             $posts = get_posts('category=12');  
             $count = count($posts);  echo $count; 
            ?>
```

but after I click on button 'Save', all php code was removed.

I really want to keep it. Anyone have any idea to keep it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to edit the widget itself or better yet extend it.

PHP code isn't allowed in the widget title field which is why it was stripped out. There may be plugins out there that allow you to override this behaviour but I'd strongly recommend avoiding those.

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Comment: I have modify code in widgets.php but I see nothing change, So now what is the solution??